# SQL Azure raise 40197 error (level 20, state 4, code 9002)

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I have a table in a SQL Azure DB (s1, 250Gb limit) with 47.000.000 records (total 3.5Gb). I tried to add a new calculated column, but after 1 hour of script execution, I get: **The service has encountered an error processing your request. Please try again. Error code 9002** After several tries, I get the same result.

Script for simple table:

```
create table dbo.works (
    work_id int not null identity(1,1) constraint PK_WORKS primary key, 
    client_id int null constraint FK_user_works_clients2 REFERENCES dbo.clients(client_id),
    login_id int not null constraint FK_user_works_logins2 REFERENCES dbo.logins(login_id),
    start_time datetime not null,
    end_time datetime not null,
    caption varchar(1000) null)
```

Script for alter:

```
alter table user_works add delta_secs as datediff(second, start_time, end_time) PERSISTED
```

Error message:

```
9002 sql server (local) - error growing transactions log file.
```

But in Azure I can not manage this param.

How can I change my structure in populated tables?

Answer (score 4):

Azure SQL Database has a 2GB transaction size limit which you are running into. For schema changes like yours you can create a new table with the new schema and copy the data in batches into this new table.

That said the limit has been removed in the latest service version V12. You might want to consider upgrading to avoid having to implement a workaround.

Comment: Last v12 update is enabled yet.
If i can't modify schema, i create new table for move data. But I try this way at first time and get same result.

Comment: may be blocks to move has been too large

Comment: Yes, you can run into the same limit when you copy data.

Answer (score 1):

Look at `sys.database_files` by connecting to the user database. If the log file current size reaches the max size then you hit this. At this point either you have to kill the active transactions or update to higher tiers (if this is not possible because of the amount of data you modifying in a single transaction).

You can also get the same by doing:

```
DBCC SQLPERF(LOGSPACE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple ideas:

1) Try creating an empty column for delta_secs, then filling in the data separately. If this still results in txn log errors, try updating part of the data at a time with a WHERE clause.

2) Don't add a column. Instead, add a view with the delta_secs column as a calculated field instead. Since this is a derived field, this is probably a better approach anyway.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx

Comment: 1) its calc field

2) view - not decision. its only sample. I need change structure sometimes (~1 time at month).